# Angular2 Unit Test - Change event in MdCheckbox is not triggered

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, angular-material2

I have a checkbox which has a (change) functions which sets a variable 'isSelected' to the event.checked value of the change function. Now I tried to test it with the help of [this question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898326/angular-material-2-trigger-change-event-in-md-checkbox-in-a-unit-test) However, I feel like the (change) event is not triggered as the 'isSelected' does not change. I also tried to use spyOn on the function which is triggered after (change) but this still returns that the function was no called (current test). Maybe someone knows how to detect the change and what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-intents-checkbox',
  templateUrl: 'intents-checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['intents-checkbox.component.scss']
})
export class IntentsCheckboxComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() intentId;

  constructor() { }

  public isSelected = false;


  intentChecked(event, intentId): void {
    this.isSelected = event.checked;
  }
}
```

The html:

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="isSelected"
             (change)="intentChecked($event, intentId)"
             class="project-checkbox">
</md-checkbox>
```

And my test so far:

```
it('should call intentChecked on change checkbox', () => {
    let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.project-checkbox'));
    de.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.intentChecked).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

( So the outcome of the test rn is that it fails because intentChecked was not called as expected ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can offer you two options:

1) Trigger `change` event on `md-checkbox` element

```
it('should call intentChecked on change checkbox', () => {
  let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.project-checkbox'));
  spyOn(component, 'intentChecked');
  de.triggerEventHandler('change', {});

  expect(component.intentChecked).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/izdpO3pRFW0YZIzq4pi1?p=preview)**

2) Trigger `click` event on inner `label` element

```
it('should call intentChecked on change checkbox', () => {
  let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.project-checkbox label'));
  let el = de.nativeElement;

  spyOn(component, 'intentChecked');

  el.click();

  expect(component.intentChecked).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tqLUphocXGrXYsAz0d2N?p=preview)**

As we want to check if `intentChecked` method was called we need to spy on this method in both cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see my error: I had an event handler on click and not change which makes obviously no sense if I have a (change) event! Thanks!