# How to test the binding of a mat-checkbox in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have an Angular 6 application and would like to test that the binding of a mat-checkbox works. I have this template:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <mat-checkbox id="singleCheckBox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

and this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isChecked: boolean;
}
```

I test it with this code:

```
import { TestBed, async, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
    ],
    }).compileComponents();
}));

it('should update the property if the checkbox is clicked (using whenStable)', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const checkBoxElement: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#singleCheckBox')).nativeElement;
    checkBoxElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(compiled.isChecked).toBe(true);
    });
}));

it('should update the property if the checkbox is clicked (using fakeAsync)', fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const checkBoxElement: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#singleCheckBox')).nativeElement;
    checkBoxElement.click();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(compiled.isChecked).toBe(true);
}));
});
```

I would expect the tests to pass but both fail with the message "Expected undefined to be true."

What am I doind wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `expect(checkBoxElement.isChecked).toBe(true);`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It pointed me into the right direction. In fact I do not want to test `expect(compiled.isChecked).toBe(true);` but `expect(fixture.componentInstance.isChecked).toBe(true);`. Together with the answer of qwrtln below, this helped me to create a valid test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the handle is in the label of the check box:

```
const checkBoxElement: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#singleCheckBox label')).nativeElement;
```

Source: [Angular Material 2 - Trigger change event in md-checkbox in a Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898326/angular-material-2-trigger-change-event-in-md-checkbox-in-a-unit-test)

Comment: Thank you, that helped! Together with fixing my expectation, as described in the comment to Amit's answer above, this made the whenStable() test pass. The fakeAsync test fails and prints the message "Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue."